# Ordenate django query by user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I'm trying to retrieve the objects that some user created and show in my API, but i need to ordenate this objects by this user. If use order_by('created_by') the queryset will be ordenate by user's id (not necessarily the id that i want, but descending order), the firsts results must be the `Opportunity` that my user created followed by the others.

I thought this could resolve, but `q` lost the ordenation with union:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    user = self.request.user
    q_all = Opportunity.objects.all().exclude(created_by=user.id)
    q_user = Opportunity.objects.filter(created_by=user.id).exclude(archived=True)
    q = q_user | q_all
    return q
```

Comment: You want to order by user name ?

Comment: Could be name or id, i simply want to show user's opportunity first than the others in queryset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) with a key method to sort the `QuerySet`.

**Solution**:

```
def sort_by_auth_user(self, item):
    if item.created_by == self.request.user:
        return -1
    else:
        return 1

def get_queryset(self):
    opp_qs = Opportunity.objects.all()
    sorted_opp_qs = sorted(opp_qs, key=self.sort_by_auth_user)
    return sorted_opp_qs
```

`sorted` method takes a list and an optional argument `key` in which you can pass a method to sort by your own custom needs.

I used that custom method to check if the `item.created_by` is authenticated user or not, for which I have returned `-1` which could be any value less than the value from other items which are not created by authenticated users.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i need